# Radiation levels on inside surface of Dyson sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, stellar-physics

A couple of things occur to me:

1. The Earth has a magnetosphere, which deflects the worst of the cosmic rays and radiation produced by Sol.
2. We have an atmosphere which scatters and further attenuates said radiation.

So, the questions raises itself: What would the radiation levels be in a Dyson sphere of radius 1AU, given that:

1. It is not guaranteed to have an equal atmosphere across the entire inner surface.
2. I don't see how it could have a magnetosphere to deflect or absorb radiation.

I suppose it, absorbing almost 100% of it's stars output could theoretically, generate an EM field, but surely that would require a mind boggling amount of energy?

So taking these things into account, surely the radiation levels on the inner surface of a Dyson sphere would be lethal to humans?

Answer (score 3):

[Dyson's original proposal](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Dyson_sphere) was a swarm of freely orbiting solar collectors, although one can also make one using [statite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statite) sails. The interior was never intended to be habitable. But people nearly instantly misunderstood the concept as a single, solid shell with a habitable interior.

This is hard to physically realise since the gravitational stresses are close to the limits of what molecular matter can handle, there is a tendency to buckle, and there is no net force keeping the sun centred. Worse for habitability, the gravity on the inside is directed "downwards" to the sun unless the shell rotates (and then the force and buckling issues become way worse). Maintaining an atmosphere and biosphere on the inside is hence pretty hard. So the cosmic ray issue is actually pretty minor.

Plus, [reflected light and waste heat](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009457659500009O) from the other parts of the interior will make it hotter/brighter than a normal planetary surface at the same solar distance.

Note that this is just dissing the solid shell biosphere model, not Dyson spheres in general! If you have a Dyson swarm you can have O'Neill habitat cylinders orbiting as part of it, and they would be as protected as any other space habitat. They could orbit outside, supplied energy and light using microwave relays and mirrors (and protected from solar radiation by the shell). And [if you want to give the habitats magnetospheres](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/how-much-power-would-a-spacecrafts-magnetic-shield-require), you have more than $10^{26}$ Watt to generate it from - Dyson spheres are *for* providing mind-boggling amounts of energy ([the proposed spacecraft shields use energy of the order of kW or MA](http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d76205x/research/Shielding/docs/ToMaSS.pdf), so there are lots of orders of magnitude to play with).

All said, the interior of a Dyson sphere at 1 AU is about as unfriendly as space in Earth orbit. But the protections can also be the same: shielded biospheres (possibly *very* large), artificial magnetospheres, indirect light etc.